# SonarQube Cycles broken?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5, sonarqube-web

My project is analysed by SonarQube for every VCS check-in and I have observed some strange behavior:

The dependency cycle-count changes to extremes every now and then.

[image: Every now and then the cycle count increases ten-fold]

When viewing the details (e.g. clicking the link) the old (smaller number) value is displayed. What could be the cause of this?

[image: The details look different]

Comment: which language is analyzed in your project ?

Comment: The project language is Java (Maven-based). Its an Android app

Comment: I can confirm that this is still an issue in SonarQube 4.5.6 LTS and Java plugin 3.13.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature has been dropped from SonarQube platform in version 5.2 thus even if there might be some flaws on this on sonar java analyzer side there is not point to make an effort to fix them as this will be dropped when it will move to LTS version 5.x

See this ticket for detailed explanation : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6553